# Capitalize 1st letter and every letter after special characters (*&^%.,) in javascript but not able to insert character at the begining

Tags: javascript, regex

I was trying this code for capitalizing, but not able to edit the characters, it automatically writes the end.

```
str.replace(new RegExp("^\\p{L} ^[\w.]+$ /(?:\b|_)([a-z])/g"), function ($1) {
    return $1.toUpperCase(); 
});
```

Its working in Safari, but not in Firefox.

Comment: Have you tried double-escaping characters correctly?

Comment: But that regexp is a serious mess. Sure it is one and not two concatenated?

Comment: JS RegExp doesn't support `\p{L}`. How is it even working?

Comment: Isn't just this enough: `str.replace(new RegExp("(?:\\b|_)([a-z])", 'g'), function($1) {return $1.toUpperCase();});`

Comment: This code isn't working at all. http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/gpRLb/

Comment: "Its working in Safari, but not in Firefox". This code doesn't even work in Safari; not on Windows, anyway. But as the others have said: this is no valid Javascript regular expression: it’s not **supposed** to work.

Comment: @dfsq That works. Make it an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second part of your regular expression is enough. Also note the you should pass `g` modifier as the second parameter:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/gpRLb/

```
str.replace(new RegExp("(?:\\b|_)([a-z])", "g"), function($1) {
    return $1.toUpperCase();
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks Your code works perfectly. But the problem is , If i want to edit the textbox at the 1st letter of the word, its automatically writes tht letter at the end. Pls find this jsfiddle.. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4ppGS/2/

Comment: If you just need to capitalize each word in text field maybe CSS will be enough http://jsfiddle.net/4ppGS/3/. But if you really need JS  then since you are using keyup event and you reset the value then this is default behavior.